# How to filter Sharepoint list in Flow by current date plus days?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I've got a Sharepoint list tracking items and renewal dates associated with them. I want to utilize MS Flow to get just the items from that list (which will eventually have about 200 items in it) that have a renewal date 60 days from now, and send an email with the info from the list. This would recur every day.

The recurring feature works fine, as does the list and email.. My issue is with filtering the list down. I had hoped to be able to use views I created in the list, couldn't find a method for that, so I've resorted to attempting to utilize the ODATA filtering option.

I use the AddToTime feature before grabbing the list to get the 60 days out date (which is returning the correct value based on the error string), but no matter what I get invalid expression when it runs on the filter.

Any guidance on this?

This is Sharepoint Online and Flow Online. An example query string that I've used is Renewal_x0020_Date eq [insert the output from the Add to time flow item before].

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!

Turns out, all I had to do was place single quotes around my object for the calculated date/time in my ODATA filter.